# `Is defining a macro via -D option ALWAYS equivalent to #define MACRO (except precedence)

Tags: macros, makefile

I have a third party piece of code that works differently when I add a macro via `Makefile` e.g. `-DMacro` instead of doing `#define MACRO` in a top level header file 
(which as their documentation implies is included in ALL files).

I Googled if there are any differences in defining it in different ways but could not come up with much except [Precedence of -D MACRO and #define MACRO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965956/precedence-of-d-macro-and-define-macro).

I am wondering if I am missing anything about make documentation / C standards before I start debugging and determining the issue.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The difference between `-D` on the compile line and `#define` in a header is that (a) it's defined for all compiles, while the header might not be included in all source files, and (b) it's defined _before_ each source file processing has begun.  The order in which the `#define` appears (before or after other header files etc.) can easily make a big difference in how the preprocessor handles the code.  You can use the compiler's `-E` flag (most compilers support it) or similar to show the preprocessed output and compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's exactly the same but neither `make` nor the ISO standard have anything to say about it. It's up to the compiler itself, some may not even *have* a `-D` option.

To `make`, it's just running the command (such as `gcc`) with whatever options it takes. ISO doesn't specify *anything* about how to run a compiler, just how the compiler (and the things it creates) behaves.

For `gcc`, the preprocessor options can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) so it looks like it *is* identical to `#define`.