# How to add #define in Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a c++ project in which i need to define a variable in some CXX files. I have nearly 800 files out of which i need to define a variable for 200 files. So i was thinking to define it in makefile. So how can we do that.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Also see [Passing a gcc flag through makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250608/608639), [Append compile flags to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS while configuration/make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23407635), [How to add compile flag -g to a make file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12898287), [Allowing users to override CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51606653), [Including a #define in all .c source files at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13127810/), [Precedence of -D MACRO and #define MACRO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3965956/) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use a header file

defining.h:

```
#define deff 10
```

main.cxx or any file where you want to use

```
#include "definitions.h"
```

The other way is while compiling give following arg
g++ -DMYDEF  file1.cpp file2.cpp ------ file200.cpp -o abc.exe

Answer (score 13):

Just add `-Dxxx=yy` on the command line (`xxx` the name of the macro and `yy` the replacement, or just `-Dxxx` if there is no value).

It's not a Makefile command, it's part of the compiler command line options.

Comment: What is xxx and yy

Comment: It means, `xxx` is the name and `yy` is the value.  For example,`#define xxx (yy)` is `-Dxxx=yy`.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you want a replacement for `#define MYDEF`

In your makefile you have the compiler command line, something like (simplest example):

```
g++ -o myfile.cpp
```

To get that #define for every `myfile.cpp` just use `-D` like so:

```
g++ -DMYDEF -o myfile.cpp
```

Answer (score 6):

I would add the compiler flag to set a macro  (`-D` for `GCC`) to the standard variable `CXXFLAGS` so it will be applied to any *implicit rule* compiler invocations:

```
CXXFLAGS += -DMY_DEFINE
```

Then add that variable to any *explicit rules* you may have:

```
target: source.cpp
    $(CXX) -std=c++14 $(CXXFLAGS) ...
```

Because the standard variables are only added with *implicit rules*.