# c++ conditional include or compile

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

i'm studying about arduino but i want to test my code by g++ compiler before adjust to arduino.

it is easy way to test if i make two same code but it makes me tiresome.

so i want to do conditional compile.

here is my code

CustomMath.cpp

```
#include "CustomMath.h"

#if defined(_CPP_)
#include <cmath>
#endif

#if defined(_ARDUINO_)
#include "math.h"
#endif

float CustomMath::cSin(int degree)
{
    float value = 2;//check for this code is work right
    float radian = cDegreeToRadian(degree);
#if defined(_CPP_)
    value = sin(radian);
#elif defined(_ARDUINO_)
    value = sin(radian);
#endif

    return value;
}
```

and here is main code

```
#define _CPP_

#include <iostream>
#include "CustomMath.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CustomMath;//CustomMath.h ic braced by namespace CustomMath

int main()
{
    cout << "sin : " << cSin(30) << endl;
}
```

and output is

```
sin : 2 <<-- this means conditional compile is not work
```

i think _CPP__ is defined after CustomMath compiled.
how can i do conditial compile? or is there something wrong?

==========================================================================

i just add ComileCondition.h

```
#define _CPP_
```

and i just change this part when i adjust on arduino

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288150/how-to-add-define-in-makefile

Comment: You've defined `_CPP_` for `main.cpp`, but neither `_CPP_` nor `_ARDUINO_` is defined when compiling `CustomMath.cpp`.

Comment: Be aware that [identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations).

Comment: Perhaps you should instead check for `#ifdef _cplusplus` (note the double under-score)

Comment: normally you would write `#include <math.h>` since it is a standard header.

Comment: @enhzflep ah thanks. this is what i want to find!